# Wrap div elements to a new line if the width is limited via max-width

Tags: javascript, html, css

You need to move div blocks to a new line and the width of the block should become the minimum width possible

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
</div>
```

In div elements can be not only text, but for example pictures of small size and so I need to do this with div

It would seem the task is not difficult but how to solve it do not understand will be glad to any idea, thanks for earlier.

I have tried the inline-block, flex and grid approach and so far I have not been able to achieve the desired result. But it turns out that there is still empty space on the right side.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by `"move div blocks to a new line and the width of the block should become the minimum width possible"` please?